# Writing a key-value store

Tags: python, key-value-store

I am looking to write a Key/value store (probably in python) mostly just for experience, and because it's something I think that is a very useful product. I have a couple of questions. How, in general, are key/value pairs normally stored in memory and on disk? How would one go about loading the things stored on disk, back into memory? Do key/value stores keep all the key/value pairs in memory at once? or is it read from the disk?

I tried to find some literature on the subject, but didn't get very far and was hoping someone here could help me out.

Comment: Just for the record there is an interesting pure Python NoSQL http://labs.codernity.com/codernitydb/

Answer (score 24):

It all depends on the level of complexity you want to dive into. Starting with a simple Python `dict` serialized to a file in a myriad of possible ways (of which pickle is probably the simplest), you can go as far as implementing a complete database system.

Look up `redis` - it's a key/value store written in C and operating as a server "DB". It has some good documentation and easy to read code, so you can borrow ideas for your Python implementation.

To go even farther, you can read about B-trees.

For your specific questions: above some DB size, you can never keep it all in memory, so you need some robust way of loading data from disk. Also consider whether the store is single-client or multi-client. This has serious consequences for its implementation.

Comment: If i could upvote this twice I would. This is the kind of answer I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Python's [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module which provides a persitent dictionary. It basically stores pickles in a database, usually dmb or BSDDB. Looking at how `shelve` works will give you some insights, and the source code comes with your python distribution.

Another product to look at is [Durus](http://www.mems-exchange.org/software/durus/). This is an object database, that it uses it's own B-tree implementation for persistence to disk.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing a key/value store in Python for learning purposes, it might be easiest to start with the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module. It's a fast and convenient way to write an arbitrary Python data stream to a persistent store and read it back again.

Answer (score 3):

you can have a look at '[Berkley db](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)' to see how how it works, it is a key/value DB, so you can use it directly, or as it is open-source see how it handles persistence, transactions and paging of most referred pages.

here are python bindings to it http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm

Comment: This answer is a what I was coming in here to write. BDB is used everywhere and implements solutions to a large number of storage problems.

Comment: I don't think he'll have much fun reading through the code, though.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon released a [document](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2FAllThingsDistributed%2Fsosp%2Famazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf&ei=E2j-SvHaOJSmsAbk68mRDA&usg=AFQjCNEpBjuspsc5JvGcLtzw39GGRN-chA&sig2=FjGnnpx1ChirGrNHNRtmeA) about Dynamo - a highly available key-value storage system. It mostly deals with the scaling issues (how to create a key/value store that runs on a large number of machines), but it also deals with some basics, and generally worth to read.

Answer (score 1):

First up, I know this question quite old.

I'm the creator of aodbm ( http://sf.net/projects/aodbm/ ), which is a key-value store library. aodbm uses immutable B+Trees to store your data. So whenever a modification is made a new tree is appended to the end of the file. This probably sounds like a horrendous waste of space, but seeing as the vast majority of nodes from the previous tree are referenced, the overhead is actually quite low. Very little of an entire tree is kept in memory at any given time (at most O(log n)).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to see the talk [Write optimization in external - memory data structures](http://www.slideshare.net/leifwalsh/writeoptimization-in-external-memory-data-structures) ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/leifwalsh/writeoptimization-in-external-memory-data-structures)), which gives a nice overview of modern approaches to building *extra-memory* databases (e. g. key-value stores), and explains [log-structured merge trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree).

If your key-value store targets use-cases when all the data fits main memory, the data store architecture could be a lot simpler, [mapping a file to a big chunk of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) and working with that memory without bothering about disk-to-memory communication and synchronization at all, because it becomes a concern of the operating system.