# DBMS with offline replicas + advanced security + queries

Tags: nosql, mapreduce, couchdb, database-replication, database

We're currently evaluating DBMS that are able to handle offline replicas (as in, replicas are allowed to stay offline for long amounts of time). CouchDB would be a prime candidate, however there are lots of drawbacks for our usecase. Some of these features we could add ourselves in some code wrapper around the DB, however some are show stoppers:

- No built-in DB-wide encryption (could be added on file level)
- No per document security (could be simulated by using multiple databases per solution)
- No built-in editor role (could be done programmatically)
- No simple queries, every lookup has to be done using map/reduce (very tough, either adds lots of development time on framework side or for each solution)

Now here is the question: Do you know of any DBMS that would add one or more of these features? Maybe there are some commercial solutions out there, possibly wrappers around CouchDB?

Answer (score 2):

You should look here: [Write heavy, replicated, bigger-than-memory key-value store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444320/write-heavy-key-value-store)

I have mentioned a very interesting universal LevelDB key-value storage ready for modifications, implemented e.g. with Riak multinode platform:

http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/07/leveldb-fast-persistent-key-value-store.html

http://basho.com/blog/technical/2011/07/01/Leveling-the-Field/

Comment: Thanks. I think my specifications were a bit too vague. In our use case I actually prefer a document oriented DB over a key-value store, hence why I was thinking about CouchDB as well. Also, I should have mentioned that we'd like to have Offline Replicas on mobiles and user notebooks. Is that possible with Riak or LevelDB?